Jitsi Scalable Configuration Issues with SSL Certificates and Connectivity, jitsi videobridge, prosody
## Jitsi Scalable Configuration Issues with SSL Certificates and Connectivity

I’m running a Jitsi Meet instance on `meet.test.com`(changed) hosted on an AWS instance. According to the Jitsi Meet handbook, no additional configurations are required for horizontal scalability beyond the default setup, which I’m using. 

From videobridge server i can connect to jitsi meet server. in 433 and 5222 port as well.

ALL required ports are opened.


      +                                       +
               |                                       |
               |                                       |
               v                                       v
          80, 443 TCP                          443 TCP, 10000 UDP
       +--------------+                     +---------------------+
       |  nginx       |  5222 TCP           |                     |
       |  Jitsi Meet  |<-------------------+|  jitsi-videobridge1 |
       |  prosody     |                     |                     |
       |  jicofo      |                     +---------------------+
       +--------------+      

The following issues are present in the logs:

### Prosody Logs
```plaintext
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/prosody/prosody.log
.. info    Client connected
.. info    Client disconnected: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
.. info    Client connected
.. info    Client disconnected: sslv3 alert certificate unknown

Jicofo Logs
Jicofo displays no specific connection info.
Jitsi Videobridge Logs (on a separate server instance)
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/jitsi/jvb.log
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
JVB 2024-11-09 04:22:26.147 WARNING: [22] [hostname=meet.test.com id=shard] MucClient.setPresenceExtensions#467: Cannot set presence extension: not connected.
...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
...

SSL Verification Test (Output Seems Valid)
The SSL certificate appears to be valid when checked with openssl:
$ openssl s_client -connect meet.test.com:443 -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R10
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = meet.test.com
verify return:1.

Main Issues

SSL Certificate Errors: The Jitsi Videobridge log shows PKIX path building failed and unable to find valid certification path to requested target, even though openssl verification for meet.test.com passes.
Prosody Client Disconnections: Prosody logs show frequent client disconnections due to sslv3 alert certificate unknown.

Given these logs and the apparently valid SSL setup, what additional steps should I take to troubleshoot and resolve these SSL certificate and connection issues in my Jitsi setup?

Check for Correct Listening on Port 5222 -listening
Certificate Chain Verification -ok
Review Prosody and Jitsi SSL Settings- ok
Add the Certificate to Trusted Store -DONE 
Import the Certificate Chain into Java’s Keystore- already Existing
Verify the Existing Certificate- 
Testing SSL Connections to the Jitsi Meet Server - work fine
>
The openssl s_client -starttls xmpp -connect meet.test.com:5222 command connecting without showing a peer certificate suggests that Prosody’s STARTTLS setup is incomplete or not enforcing STARTTLS on this connection.
>Enable and Verify STARTTLS for Client-to-Server (c2s) Connections
>Checking the Certificate Permissions - ok 

Define ssl Globally - same error - revert back

...... SO ON ...

